# How to use javascript to create breadcrumbs?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, document.write

I'm new to javascript and so I know I'm missing something, but I just cannot tell what it is that I'm missing.

I'm creating a widget for Adobe Muse and i'm wanting to make it possible for a user to add or remove breadcrumbs inside the widget. The widget allows a user to set a true or a false value and I'm using the document.write function to write the code. The widget uses schema.org markup hence the itemprop itemscope whatnot.

Here's what the script looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var crumb2 = "true";
    var crumb3 = "true";
        if (crumb2 == "true") {
            document.write("<span>Crumb2</span><span itemscope itemtype='http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb'><a href='crumb2.html' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='title'>Crumb2 Title</span></a></span>");
        } else if (crumb3 == "true") {
            document.write("<span>Crumb3</span><span itemscope itemtype='http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb'><a href='crumb3.html' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='title'>Crumb3 Title</span></a></span>");
        }
</script>
```

From what I think I understand, once the first variable is read as true, it will ignore the rest of the variables (at least when the code is written in the way I have written it). Assuming that this is true, how can I get it to not do that (for lack of correct terminology)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `document.write`? There must be a better way.

That said your question is how do I have more than one conditional process regardless of the previous conditional's outcome? The answer is don't use the `else` portion.

```
if (true) {
  // Will exuecute
} else if (true) {
  // Will never execute
}
```

VS

```
if (true) {
  // Will execute
}
if (true) {
  // Will execute
}
```

To follow up on the `document.write` comment, I don't know Adobe Muse but if it's in the browser you should use the DOM API (or jQuery) to manage changes. `document.write` is a very slippery slope and bad practice.

Instead why not a function like this:

```
function makeCrumElement(url, title) {
  var root = document.createElement('span');
  root.setAttribute('itemscope');
  root.setAttribute('itemtype', 'http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb');
  var aTag = document.createElement('a');
  aTag.setAttribute('itemprop', 'url');
  aTag.setAttribute('href', url);
  var spanTitle = document.createElement('span');
  spanTitle.setAttribute('itemprop', 'title');
  var titleText = document.createTextNode(title);
  spanTitle.appendChild(titleText);
  aTag.appendChild(spanTitle);
  root.appendChild(aTag);
  return root;
}
```

Or use `innerHTML`:

```
function makeCrumElement(url, title) {
  var root = document.createElement('span');
  root.setAttribute('itemscope');
  root.setAttribute('itemtype', 'http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb');
  root.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">' + title + '</span></a>';
  return root;
}
```

Or with jQuery:

```
function makeCrumElement(url, title) {
  var root = $('<span><a><span></span></a></span>')
    .attr({
      itemscope: true,
      itemtype: 'http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb'
    });
  root.find('a')
    .attr({
      itemtype: 'url'
      href: url
    })
    .find('span')
    .attr({
      itemprop: 'title'
    })
    .text(title);
  return root;
}
```

Comment: That did it! What would you recommend instead of document.write?

Comment: holyyyy s@&% thank you so, so much for going into detail on this! This helps so much

Comment: I've got one more question. How do I use these with true/false if statements? Again, thank you so much.

Comment: That seemed out of scope for the question so instead here is a [JSBin illustrating the concept](http://jsbin.com/nalavu/1/edit?js,output).